# Can I connect a 16x2 LCD screen to the 5V GPIO?

Tags: gpio

From what I've seen of articles and videos online, everyone seems to be using the 3.3V GPIO pin. I have an LCD screen which requires a 5V power supply and I wondered whether it would be safe to use the Raspberry Pi's 5V GPIO pin? If you can't use it, what is it there for?

I have a 16x2 KS0066 (apparently compatible with HD44780) LCD screen
[image: Picture of LCD screen]

Comment: As long as the LCD does not need more than 200ma (assuming you are using 1A supply on model B) then you are fine to use it as supply. Model B can peak at 800ma so 200ma is safe to use as spare from the 5V Pin. If you need more use another power supply/board to connect direct to the power supply if it is more than 1A

Comment: I bought this before I knew what I was doing:
http://www.oomlout.co.uk/lcd-display-16-x-2-p-212.html
The technical specifications seem to indicate it will draw 1.2mA@5V.

Comment: I think the 5V pin gives you less than 5V because it is subject to use by other resources, however the 3V3 is consistently 3V3. I am not with my Pi until weekend but use a multimeter (if you have one) and you will see you don't get the full 5V.

Comment: @AnthonyBlake because the 5V is not regulated on pcb but supplied by external power. 3v3 is regulated from the 5V rail. A slight voltage drop will not affect this LCD screen.

Comment: @ppumkin ah okay, I am quite new to electronics so I didnt know if that would have an effect.

Answer (score 11):

There is a brilliant [tutorial at Adafruit](http://learn.adafruit.com/drive-a-16x2-lcd-directly-with-a-raspberry-pi/) how to connect a 16x2 LCD to the Raspberry Pi using the 6 I/O pins.

[image]

As this is just a small LCD screen and you said in your comments it only uses 1.2mA you will be perfectly fine to use the +5V GPIO Pin to power the LCD .

When you want to use more peripherals though you would have to look into using an I<sup>2</sup>C interface instead.

Comment: the link works perfectly fine for raspberry pi model b 2 if all the pins are correctly configured.  Thanks @ppumkin

Answer (score 1):

Go for it! You should, of course, look at the [schematic](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/1090) and note their is a 1A fuse on the supply; depending on your USB peripherals you will be limited to between 200 - 500mA. If this is not enough, [you could power the Raspberry Pi via the 5V pin](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/1617/86).

Answer (score 1):

It should be fine. The backlight is the main power user, and it's typically only 20mA in addition to the 1mA that the LCD part uses.