# TelNet to 2 LCDs

Tags: python

Is there a way to use two LCDs with this script that uses `TelNet` to add strings to the screens?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import telnetlib;
import time;
import os;
import subprocess;

host='127.0.0.1';
port='13666';
data = ""



tn = telnetlib.Telnet(host, port)
tn.write("hello\r");

data += tn.read_until("\n");
tn.write("screen_add my_screen\n");
data += tn.read_until("\n");

tn.write("screen_set my_screen 1 -heartbeat off\n");
data += tn.read_until("\n");

tn.write("widget_add my_screen 1 scroller\n");
data += tn.read_until("\n");

tn.write("widget_add my_screen 2 scroller\n");
data += tn.read_until("\n");


var = 1;
while var == 1 :

  cmd1 = "mpc | head -1"        #gets the currently playing song from mpc
  process = subprocess.Popen(cmd1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE , shell=True)
  os.waitpid(process.pid, 0)[1]
  mpc_song = process.stdout.read().strip()

  cmd2 = "mpc | grep vol | cut -d% -f1 | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'"    #gets the volume level from mpc
  process = subprocess.Popen(cmd2, stdout=subprocess.PIPE , shell=True)
  os.waitpid(process.pid, 0)[1]
  mpc_vol = process.stdout.read().strip()

  cmd3 = "mpc | head -2 | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}'" # gets the player state ie paused playing etc
  process = subprocess.Popen(cmd3, stdout=subprocess.PIPE , shell=True)
  os.waitpid(process.pid, 0)[1]
  mpc_state = process.stdout.read().strip()

  cmd4 = "hostname -I"  #gets the current ip of the boombox
  process = subprocess.Popen(cmd4, stdout=subprocess.PIPE , shell=True)
  os.waitpid(process.pid, 0)[1]
  ip_addr = process.stdout.read().strip()

  cmd5 = "netstat -t | grep rfe" #check if a user is connected via airplay
  process = subprocess.Popen(cmd5, stdout=subprocess.PIPE , shell=True)
  os.waitpid(process.pid, 0)[1]
  airplay = process.stdout.read().strip()

  cmd6 = "iwconfig wlan0 | grep Signal | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d= -f2" #check wifi signal strength
  process = subprocess.Popen(cmd6, stdout=subprocess.PIPE , shell=True)
  os.waitpid(process.pid, 0)[1]
  wifi_strength = process.stdout.read().strip()


  if airplay:  ##If airplay is in use, pause MPC and display Airplay Mode on LCD else display mpc data as normal
    mpc_pause = "mpc pause"
    process = subprocess.Popen(mpc_pause, stdout=subprocess.PIPE , shell=True)
    tn.write("widget_set my_screen 1 1 1 16 1 m 5 \"Airplay Mode\"\n");
    data += tn.read_until("\n");
  else:
    tn.write("widget_set my_screen 1 1 1 16 1 m 8 \"%s \" \n" % (mpc_song));
    data += tn.read_until("\n");
  timenow = time.strftime('%H:%M');
  tn.write("widget_set my_screen 2 1 2 16 2 m 4 \"Time:%s | Vol:%s | IP:%s | Signal: %s \"\n" % (timenow, mpc_vol,ip_addr,wifi_strength));
  data += tn.read_until("\n"); 

  time.sleep(5)
```

It looks really great but I don't know how to use it if you have 2 screens. Currently I am using the Pi pins for this script. But i have a `MCP23017` so i can use that for the two screens.

Comment: Are the LCDs HD47780 based and hooked up something like [this](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/1770/590)?

Comment: Yes they are hooked up like that, and they are hd47780

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this script is designed to work with [LCDproc](http://lcdproc.omnipotent.net/).

You can either

1. scrap the telnet part altogether and extend [my example code](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/1770/590). Basically you would replace all the `tn.write(...)` with a call to `lcd_string`. You'll have to work out what all the parameters do for the `"widget_set ..."` etc.
2. Write a driver for LCDproc to support your setup