# Connecting an LCD display to the Raspberry Pi

Tags: hardware

I am very very new to the raspberry pi, and get frustrated at things as simple as breadboards, so please bare with me. I have an LCD screen, 4 rows, 20 characters on each row, so very small, and I was wondering if there was any way at all to get it hooked up to my pi so that it could be like a tiny pocket sized terminal thing. The software would be the easy part, I could install many choices that were terminal based, but getting the screen connected is the big part. What do you guys think? Can it be done, and if so, how?

[image]

Comment: Here are some ways to connect it: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/1661/590

Answer (score 1):

why don't you google your question first?

on the very first page you'll get https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/gpio-examples/lcd-interface/ that explains everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways to approach this. The first way would be to write a kernel driver for a frame-buffer device on the LCD display. This is prohibitively complex. The second way I know would be to create a terminal emulator program (emulating vt100 for example) and then have this launch in place of tty0. The keyboard input would go into the application, but the display would come up on the screen. This would probably be the best way to do it if the vt100 terminal protocol made any sense at all. Unfortunately, from when I looked into this it's miles and miles of spaghetti to me.

That leaves the third way, which wouldn't quite work perfectly, but would work "good enough" for very basic usage. Write a program to run in place of tty0 that executes a command, captures its output as text, and write that to the display. Something like the python subprocess command would do this. You'd read in a line of text, execute it as a command, capture the string output of running it, and then display that.

I would dearly love it if someone managed to hack vt100 so that that idea would work though...