# Raspberry pi power cable is unstable

Tags: power

The slightest bump, or knock to the micro power connection and my pi reboots.

Anyone have this have problem?

I wouldn't feel secure releasing a product that is so delicate.

Comment: I've just tried flicking the connection on two Pis.  No reboots.  Do you have another cable?

Comment: Micro USB is crap! I can confirm this behavior with my home pi. With the Pi in a case the connector barely sticks properly. (However this question is also not very specific and bordering a close vote.)

Comment: I beg to differ, this is a specific problem that could hold up progress. The slightest physical jolt to the convective port/chord  and my pi reboots.

Comment: Well your question is actually whether anybody else has this problem - the answer being "yes". So I'd argue that the question is poorly phrased to attract helpful answers. Is "what to do about it?" not more what you'd like to know?

Comment: You still have not made a useful point.

Comment: Your question, your call. If you get the answers you're looking for, that's fine with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new power source works perfectly.
I must have damaged the clamps on the cable.

Hard to notice since they're so small.

I'm working now.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with the first cable I used on my Pi.  Turns out the problem was me using an old cable.  Original micro USB had the securing pins built into the plug, not the cable.

If you're not using a cable with pins built onto it, try a cable that does.  If you are, try another cable anyway.  I've seen several different Pi's used with a variety of cables and have only ever had that one issue.

Comment: Would you happen to be using a cell phone charger? That's what I'm using. I guess that's not good enough?

Comment: Also, I'm using the fist pi released.

Comment: @MichaelClayton: I am using a cell phone charger.

Answer (score 1):

> I wouldn't feel secure releasing a product that is so delicate.

There's another way of providing power to the Pi. You can provide 5V to the GPIO 5V rail, but **be aware**:

1. You are bypassing Pi's PSU, which means: You have no voltage regulation. You need to make sure you give 5V, **exactly 5.0 V**, Otherwise your Pi would die.
2. You are bypassing the fuse. So You have no protection.
3. I am not sure but i heard that doing so voids the warranty.

More detailed answer: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/1619/21993

Comment: That's too extreme a solution for my taste. Ill look into a new cable. The slightest power surge would destroy my product.

Comment: @MichaelClayton There are cheap circiuts like `LM7805` which will make sure that your pi is going to get tight 5V. The micro usb power inlet is more likely to get broken in the future, so ping aren't a bad idea. They are just another way of providing power, more more advanced users.

Answer (score 0):

From what I hear, it seems like a bad Micro USB cable. Your phone's charging cable is most likely Micro USB, try your Pi with that one.

Comment: That's my point, the current cable it's my phone charger cable.

Comment: Does it show this same flakiness on your phone? If not, it may be your Pi.