# powering raspberry pi B+ through the USB port

Tags: boot, peripherals, alternative-power

I am enclosing my raspberry pi B+ into a camera case due to which the micro USB power plug on the pi is not accessible, I was thinking of powering it through the normal USB port. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lGELwCXeNTs this shows powering a raspberry pi B through a USB port. Not sure how to do this for my raspberry pi B+. I have tried powering it through USB port but the didnt boot up. 
Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't back-power the B+ through USB, the only other way than the micro USB is via GPIO, see [How do I supply power through the GPIO?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1617/how-do-i-supply-power-through-the-gpio)

Comment: To be pedantic you can't power through the gpio (you will damage your Pi if you try to do so), you power through the power and ground rail pins on the expansion header.