# Safe to power Raspberry Pi 3 with 5.25 v out of BEC?

Tags: power-supply

So I'm using a Lipo to power my Pi 3 and to be safe, I installed a 5v 3A UBEC. Upon checking the voltage output, I saw the BEC was only stepping the voltage down to around 5.25v, rather than 5v. I know this is pushing the recommended max voltage. Do you think it will be Ok? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**5.25 V should be acceptable.**

As noted in [Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations):

> Power sources SHOULD provide 5±0.25V and often list a current rating

I couldn't find any explicit mention of voltage in the [Pi FAQ](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#powerReqs), but it turns out that the voltage constraint is part of the [USB standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB). Note that the tolerance listed there is 4.40 — 5.25 V (in the sidebar).

See also in the [RetroPie overclocking documentation](https://github.com/RetroPie/RetroPie-Setup/wiki/Overclocking):

> The Pi runs off 5V but there's nothing wrong with a power supply providing 5.1V or 5.25V. There's usually about 0.25V drop over a typical USB power cable so the extra voltage helps compensate.

Increasing the voltage too much further could cause damage, but you're not in that range yet:

> One way to increase that reliability is to increase the voltage to the component. This has the tradeoff that more heat is generated by the component. A component may be damaged if too much voltage is supplied.

As long as the heat doesn't get excessive, and you don't go above 5.25 V, you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. There's one more thinf that I'm wondering. The BEC outputs power to just a simple + and - wire.  What would be the best way to send power to the Pi? I know I can power it off two of the GPIO pins, but I have heard it's safer to go through USB. Should I use an existing micro usb cable and solder that to the BEC, or is there a way to hard solder the power wires onto the pads where the USB port is soldered to the Pi on the underside? Thanks!

Comment: @RobRoberts Using the GPIO does lose some protections, yes, so I'd advise avoiding it if possible. Does the picture and advice in [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/1618/58316) help (mainly the bottom one with the USB adapters)?

Comment: @RobRoberts I would not lose sleep over powering the Pi with 5.25 V, not only is it within the USB spec that is referenced for the Pi too; it is also noteworthy that all on-board components are powered via a voltage regulator nonetheless, nothing to worry. WRT the question in the comments, I would suggest going through the micro-USB port. But please note that new questions should rather be posted as new question (unless they are already there, of course).

Comment: @RobRoberts You can buy a DIY micro-USB plug and solder your +/- wires to that. A bit tricky, but I've done it and it works great.  Then you power through the Pi's usual connector and don't have to bypass anything.